# Xamarin Forms update package

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I just upgrade my Xamarin Essentials to 1.3.1 and now I am getting a error related to System.Collections in the iOS project . **No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" **

**Is there another nuget package I need?**

```
Xamarin.Essentials                  {1.3.1}                                  
Microsoft.AppCenter.Push            {2.1.1}                                  
NETStandard.Library                 {2.0.3}                                  
Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes         {2.1.1}                                  
Xamarin.Forms                       {4.2.0.815419}


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to resolve "System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1" reference from "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"
```

Comment: try to uninstall the nuget and reinstall,then rebuild

Comment: Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.815419 is causing the issue when using VS2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time you need to use Xamarin.Forms nuget packages version 4.2.0.778463. using Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.815419 creates this problem.